# Display agents (custom post type) alphabetically, except one who always shows last

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, wp-query

I would like to display all agents a-z, except there is one agent who should always show up last. Ideally I'd like the ordering to be done from the value of a custom field, dName.

I was looking around it seemed that meta_query was the new best way to do this but haven't figured it out yet.

Current code that shows 10 last agents created.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'agents', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); ?>
```

Thanks for looking.

edit 3/27/2011, working code

```
<?php 
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'agents',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'meta_key' => 'rw_dname',
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 'key' => 'rw_dName' )
        ),
    'post__not_in' => array( '98' ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

$loop2 = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'agents',
    'post__in' => array( '98' ) ) );?>
<?php
if($loop->have_posts() || $loop2->have_posts()) { 
    if($loop->have_posts()) { while($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post();?>
<div class="agentContent">
    <div class="agentThumbnail">
        <?php 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail();
}?>
</div>
<div class="agentInfo"> <span class="agentInfoEntry">
        <?php
$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rw_dname', true);
echo $meta; // if you want to show
?>
        </span> </div>
</div>
<?php
        } //endwhile
    }
?>
<?php
if($loop2->have_posts()) { while($loop2->have_posts()) { $loop2->the_post();?>
<div class="agentContent">
    <div class="agentThumbnail">
    <?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
</div>
    <div class="agentInfo"> <span class="agentInfoEntry">
    <?php
$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rw_dname', true);
echo $meta; // if you want to show
?>
        </span> </div>
</div>
<?php
        } //endwhile
    }
?>
<?php
} else {
    echo 'No Agents.';
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the value of the field dName for the one you want to show up last?  What should happens that agent it is not in the natural order of the 10; you still want it included?

Comment: the value of the field dName is "firstname lastname" without the quotes. I want to show all the agents not just the 10, the code above was just to show what I was currently using to show the agents.

Comment: Is the agent that shows last using accented characters in his/her name?

Comment: nope, just a-z and A-Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote this up so I have not tested it but this is how I would go about forcing one post to be at the end. In the first loop it excludes the posts by its ID number and in the second loop it only includes the post by the ID number, essentially you will need to know the ID of the post.

```
<?php 
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'agents',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'dName',
    'post__not_in' => array( 00 ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
$loop2 = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'agents',
    'post__in' => array( 00 ) ) );

if($loop->have_posts() || $loop2->have_posts()) { 
    if($loop->have_posts()) { while($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post();
        echo the_title();
        echo get_post_custom_values('dName');
        //Post Content
        } //endwhile
    }
    if($loop2->have_posts()) { while($loop2->have_posts()) { $loop2->the_post();
        echo the_title();
        echo get_post_custom_values('dName');
        //Post Content
        } //endwhile
    }
} else {
    echo 'No Agents.';
}
?>
```

Comment: I guess you missed the both `endif;` curly brackets for the loops. On the other side: Why are you questioning 2 times if `$loop->have_posts()`?

Comment: There's two loops there, look closely.

Comment: @imHavoc ok I finally had some time this evening to take a look at this, I understand the logic of what is going on, but the closest I've gotten so far is "no agents"

Comment: and the rest of my comment. I edited my original question with the current pages code, which results in this, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in ... on line 27" The closest I've gotten to anything showing up is "NoAgents" after commenting out all parts of loop2. Thanks again for any help.

Comment: @Chuck - I missed the closing parenthesis in loop2. To fix the Parse error add another parenthesis to the ends so it should look like this `'post__in' => array( 00 ) ) );`. As for why the loops is not working, I will need to look into that.

Comment: @Chuck - I have updated the code to reflect that you do not actually need the `meta_query` param to use the `orderby`, instead it uses the `meta_key` param, which although by WP Codex is deprecated is has been established here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10941/how-do-you-use-orderby-with-meta-query-in-wordpress-3-1 that orderyby still needs the meta_key. This changes the loops, which may give you different results and not get the if statement to jump to No Agents. Try it again and tell me if you have any problems.

Comment: @imHavoc thanks so much it's working now, I've updated the code in my post to reflect the working code, I had to get dname differently than you specified, thanks again.