# Custom query with orderby meta_value of custom field

Tags: custom-field, query-posts

Aa you know, as of WP3.0 there are options for custom advanced queries, which is great.
As of this, some query parameters of custom fields like meta_key, meta_value were deprecated for the new meta_query parameter ([see here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters))

I try to have a pretty simple query with the new syntax, query posts by a certain post_type (services) that contains a specified meta_key (order_in_archive)- this is going well as expected. 
But - I want to orderby the query by the meta_value, and with no success.

This is my query -

```
   query_posts(
    array(  'post_type' => 'services',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array('key' => 'order_in_archive'))
    )
);
```

I tried orderby also by meta_value_numeric and meta_value, but in any case the results are being ordered by the publication date (as regular posts do).
Anyone know how can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can define the meta key for *orderby* parameter using the old method (I tested on WP 3.1.1)...

```
query_posts(
    array(  'post_type' => 'services',
            'order'     => 'ASC',
            'meta_key' => 'some_key',
            'orderby'   => 'meta_value', //or 'meta_value_num'
            'meta_query' => array(
                                array('key' => 'order_in_archive',
                                      'value' => 'some_value'
                                )
                            )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 32):

**This issue in general is cleared up as of WordPress 4.2** by using named queries. e.g.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'services',
  'orderby'   => 'order_clause',
  'meta_query' => array(
       'order_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'order_in_archive',
            'value' => 'some_value',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC' // unless the field is not a number
)));
```

For me, I wanted to order by a numeric field and I had to use `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` inside the meta query.

Comment: Awesome find on the named queries!

Comment: Yep, named queries answered the question for me, too.

Comment: Excellent.  I'm not sure the significance of 'value' in that order_clause because it's not required as it will order it by the highest to lowest value of 'order_in_archive'.

Answer (score 12):

The WP Codex is actually confusing when addressing this problem.

You do not actually need the meta_query param to use the orderby, instead it uses the meta_key param, which although by WP Codex is deprecated is has been established here: [How do you use orderby with meta_query in Wordpress 3.1?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10941/how-do-you-use-orderby-with-meta-query-in-wordpress-3-1) that orderyby still needs the meta_key.

so it should be

```
query_posts( array(
  'post_type' => 'services',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'meta_key' => 'order_in_archive'
) )
```

Comment: Well, yes, this is the old method for doing this query and it appears to be working for this specified one. Anyway, for more complex queries, it won't work. I found this is a known issue that is being taken care of, details can be found in trac tickets [#15031](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15031) and [#17065](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17065)

Comment: I was using the Toolset plugin to create custom attributes, to use the 'slug' of a custom attribute for the filter I had to prefix it with `wpcf-`. E.G. `'meta_key' => 'wpcf-order_in_archive'`

Answer (score 4):

It´s easy:

Here is my code:

```
query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'directors',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order'    => 'ASC',
        'orderby'  => 'director_weight',
        'meta_key' => 'director_weight'
) );
```

The main detail is: include `meta_key`, my code didn´t order unless `meta_key` is included, and that's all:

Here is the full code of a list of `directors` pictures order by `director_weight`:

```
<?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'directors',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order'    => 'ASC',
        'orderby'  => 'director_weight',
        'meta_key' => 'director_weight'
    ) );
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>  
    <li <?php echo get_field('director_weight') ?>>
        <img src="<?php echo get_field('director_imagen') ?>">
    </li>
<?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

[image: order_by custom fiel wordpress]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use [query_posts.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

```
$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );

$meta_query_args = array(
   'post_type' => 'services',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'your_key',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value', //or 'meta_value_num'
    'meta_query' => array(
                    array('key' => 'order_in_archive',
                        'value' => 'some_value'
)));
```

Use the [WP_Meta_Query parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)

Answer (score 1):

I had a set of custom event dates I needed to sort by date descending. Since my custom event date was stored in my wp_postmeta table, and was typically different to the post_date or modified dates, this worked for me:

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events', // my post type - yours can be 'posts'
    'post_status' => 'publish', // only get posts with this status
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', // orderby the meta_value of the following meta_key
    'meta_key' => 'my_custom_eventdate', // the custom meta_key name
    'order'=> 'DESC' // sort descending
  );

  $posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

You can then loop through $posts like so:

```
foreach($posts->posts as $p){

    $post_id = $p->ID;
    // and so on ...

    // # example of how I retrieve my event date
    $event = get_post_meta($post_id, 'my_custom_eventdate', true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following solution works:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'services',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby'   => 'order_clause',   
    'meta_query' => array(
        'order_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'order_in_archive'
        )
    )
);
```

You needed to provide the key of the meta_query sub array `order_clause` for your `orderby` value.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work quite well.

```
<?php 
query_posts(
array(  'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'post_type' => 'services',
        'order'     => 'DESC',
        'meta_key' => '_order',
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num', //or 'meta_value_num'
      )
);
```

Comment: The question is about the new-ish `meta_query` parameter and getting an `orderby` to work with it, and not about the older but still functional `meta_key`/`meta_value` parameters. Also, let's not encourage the use of `query_posts`.

Comment: This answer contains multiple bad practices: using -1, passing it as a string, using query_posts. It should be removed.