# How to List Events by Year and Month Using Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: query, date-time, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type "Kalender_item" with a custom Date Field (YYMMDD). I want to list all the posts on a page sorted by Year and Month.

For example:

- November 2012 (all events that occure in November 2012)
- December 2012 (all events that occure in December 2012)

And so on...

I have succeeded in ordering them like so

```
$kalenderItems=query_posts('post_type=kalender_item&post_status=publish&meta_key=kalender_item_datum&orderby=meta_value');
```

This gives me all my posts in the correct order. Now I want to group them by Month Year and display the Month Year as a title for each group.
How to group my results by year and month?

Comment: Hi and welcome, I'm not sure if I interpreted well your original question. Please confirm, and if not, edit it again :)

Comment: @brasofilo you interpreted it correctly. Any chance you can help me out?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a similar setup to test this scenario. Take a look at this [search query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Borderby+%2Bmeta_key+%2Bmeta_value&submit=search). Confirm the [Custom Fields arguments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for the query. Maybe format the `query_posts` [like this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15499/12615). Or, more important, use [WP_Query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/12615) instead. Have you checked ACF forums?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
<?php

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'   => 'kalender_item',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key'    => 'kalender_item_datum',
    'orderby'     => 'meta_value'
) );

# This will hold what group we're in
$current_header = '';

# The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();

    # get the datum for this post
    $temp_date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'kalender_item_datum', true );

    # If they aren't the same, we'll start a new group, which for now
    # just means setting a new heading
    if ( $temp_date != $current_header ) {
        $current_header = $temp_date;
        echo "<h2>$current_header</h2>";
    }

    # ... do normal loop stuff here

endwhile;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the help I was looking for. 
Now it looks so simple. That's what you get when designers want to develop.