# Custom taxonomy - custom sortable column

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, columns

I've created custom taxonomy called 'cities' where you can add cities and added custom field ( radio button ) with 2 options: 'Yes' and 'No' ( never mind what that is ).
Everythins is ok, I can get that value and other stuff.

Later on I came with idea to add a sortable column ( Like 'Name', 'Slug', 'Posts' etc. ).
I've managed to create that column, make it sortable but don't know how to sort those cities by that custom field? Right now it's sorting by name, because I can't get it to work with custom field.

Any clues/hints maybe?

Comment: How have you added the custom field?

Comment: with ACF plugin.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem and managed to solve it. In my case I have a custom taxonomy, `issue`, which contains a required date picker custom field using the [ACF PRO](http://advancedcustomfields.com) plugin—the field name is `issue_date`. I wanted to add the date column to my `issue` edit screen at `wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=issue` and I wanted to allow admins to sort issues by date.

I tried hooking into `pre_get_posts` as @aifrim answered above, but that action is not part of the query that runs when WordPress loads taxonomy terms into the edit screen. Furthermore, taxonomy terms don't have any native metadata in the WordPress database so a `meta_query` will not work because my metadata is stored in another table altogether. A fun curveball.

**Step 1:** Create the new column itself, it will be empty initially

```
function create_date_column_for_issues($issue_columns) {
  $issue_columns['date'] = 'Date';
  return $issue_columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-issue_columns', 'create_date_column_for_issues');
```

**Step 2:** Populate the new column

```
function populate_date_column_for_issues($value, $column_name, $term_id) {
  $issue = get_term($term_id, 'issue');
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('issue_date', $issue));
  switch($column_name) {
    case 'date': 
      $value = $date->format('Y/m/d');
    break;
    default:
    break;
  }
  return $value;    
}
add_filter('manage_issue_custom_column', 'populate_date_column_for_issues', 10, 3);
```

**Step 3:** Make the new column sortable

```
function register_date_column_for_issues_sortable($columns) {
  $columns['date'] = 'issue_date';
  return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-issue_sortable_columns', 'register_date_column_for_issues_sortable');
```

**Step 4:** Define the custom sorting (where the magic happens)

```
function sort_issues_by_date($pieces, $taxonomies, $args) {
  global $pagenow;
  if(!is_admin()) {
    return $pieces;
  }

  if(is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' && $taxonomies[0] == 'issue' && (!isset($_GET['orderby']) || $_GET['orderby'] == 'issue_date')) {
    $pieces['join']   .= " INNER JOIN wp_options AS opt ON opt.option_name = concat('issue_',t.term_id,'_issue_date')";
    $pieces['orderby'] = "ORDER BY opt.option_value";
    $pieces['order']   = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : "DESC";
  }

  return $pieces;
}
add_filter('terms_clauses', 'sort_issues_by_date', 10, 3);
```

My conditional statement in step 4 will also sort descending by `issue_date` as the default sorting when there is no other sorting criteria set.

I hope this helps someone else looking to make a better admin experience!

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't have more upvotes. It's a very helpful answer.

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Answer (score 7):

Many thanks to @cfx for this answer. Now that WP has Term Meta support, I updated Step 4 to take advantage of that. This solution borrows from this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/246206/85388 which shows how to connect a meta_query to an orderby.

```
add_filter('pre_get_terms', 'uh_service_type_taxonomy__orderby');
function uh_service_type_taxonomy__orderby( $term_query ) {
  global $pagenow;
  if(!is_admin()) {
    return $term_query;
  }
  // WP_Term_Query does not define a get() or a set() method so the query_vars member must
  // be manipulated directly
  if(is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' && $term_query->query_vars['taxonomy'][0] == 'uh_service_type_taxonomy' && (!isset($_GET['orderby']) || $_GET['orderby'] == 'term_order')) {
    // set orderby to the named clause in the meta_query
    $term_query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'order_clause';
    $term_query->query_vars['order'] = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : "DESC";
    // the OR relation and the NOT EXISTS clause allow for terms without a meta_value at all
    $args = array('relation' => 'OR',
      'order_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'taxonomy_term_order',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'taxonomy_term_order',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
      )
    );
    $term_query->meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $args );
  }
  return $term_query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A custom field is a custom post meta data made by the user or a theme/plugin, in this case that custom field is named yesno.

To add a column for it to posts or custom post types (myposttype):

```
add_filter('manage_edit-myposttype_columns', 'my_custom_columns');
function my_custom_columns($columns) {
    $columns['yesno'] = 'Yes/No';
    return $columns;
}
```

This is how you make the newly added column sortable:

```
add_filter('manage_edit-myposttype_sortable_columns', 'my_sortable_columns');
function my_sortable_columns($columns)
{
    $columns['yesno'] = 'yesno';
    return $columns;
}
```

And this is how you sort it

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sort_my_posts');
function sort_my_posts($query)
{
    if (!is_admin())
        return;
    $orderby = $query->get('orderby');
    if ($orderby == 'yesno') {
        $query->set('meta_key', 'yesno');
        $query->set('orderby', 'yesno');
    }
}
```

And it will sort them asc or desc for the Yes or No values that are saved in the meta data.

Is this what you have been looking for?

Comment: Sorry for answering this late after your post, but in the mean time I moved to the new project and fixed this with jQuery but  I will bookmark this link ( I believe I'll encounter the same problem once again ) and answer after I try this code.

Comment: @mihajloWR please let me know of the problems you will encounter because I see myself in the future in need of such a code.

Answer (score 0):

for me, I made a custom taxonomy and in that custom taxonomy I had a custom meta. I wanted to have in the admin backend a column and made it sortable. to make sortable work for a custom taxonomy in a custom meta I did this.

https://pastebin.com/vr2sCKzX

```
public function pre_get_terms( $query ) {
    $meta_query_args = array(
        'relation' => 'AND', // Optional, defaults to "AND"
        array(
            'key'     => 'order_index',
            'value'   => 0,
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    );
    $meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );
    $query->meta_query = $meta_query;
    $query->orderby = 'position_clause';
}
```

I found the answer in this link https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34996

I just had to adapt the answer provided in the comments by @eherman24

Answer (score 0):

> For admin taxonomy table sortable column it's perfect solution. Add
> any custom field in specific term so this field value column sorting .
> Also add this code in your active theme's functions.php file.
> [image]

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-{taxonomy-name}_sortable_columns' ), 'callback_term_sortable_columns_func'));
 function callback_term_sortable_columns_func( $columns ) 
    {
        $columns['column-name'] = 'column-name';
        return $columns;
    }
add_filter('pre_get_terms', 'callback_filter_terms_clauses');
function callback_filter_terms_clauses( $term_query ) 
    {
        global $pagenow;
        if(!is_admin()) { return $term_query; }
        if(is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' && (!isset($_GET['orderby']) || $_GET['orderby'] == 'column-name')) 
        {
            $term_query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
            $term_query->query_vars['order'] = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : "DESC";
            $args = array('relation' => 'OR',
                            'order_clause' => array(
                                'key' => '{term_meta_key}',
                                'type' => 'STRING'
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key' => 'taxonomy_term_order',
                                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key' => 'taxonomy_term_order',
                                'compare' => '='
                            )
                        );
            $term_query->meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $args );
        }
        return $term_query;
    }
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem? Explain your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).