# Sort posts by custom fields value using dropdown menu

Tags: php, custom-field, sort

I'm trying to sort my posts by a custom field value, called price. Only using numbers in the custom field value. I want that the visitors of the website can sort the posts on price by using a dropdown. I searched for a plugin, but couldn't found that. Now u found the code below:

```
<?php
  $order = "&order=DESC";
  if ($_POST['select'] == 'tag') { $order = "&tag=mytag";  }
  if ($_POST['select'] == 'title') { $order = "&order=ASC&orderby=title";  }
  if ($_POST['select'] == 'newest') { $order = "&order=DESC"; }
  if ($_POST['select'] == 'oldest') { $order = "&order=ASC";  }
  if ($_POST['select'] == 'mcommented') { $order = "&order=DESC&orderby=comment_count";  }
  if ($_POST['select'] == 'lcommented') { $order = "&order=ASC&orderby=comment_count";  }
  if ($_POST['select'] == 'prijs') { $order = "&order=ASC&orderby=meta_value_num";  }
?>
<form method="post" id="order">
  Sort reviews by:
  <select name="select" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
    <option value="tag"<?php selected( $_POST['select'],'tag', 1 ); ?>>Tag</option>
    <option value="title"<?php selected( $_POST['select'],'title', 1 ); ?>>Title</option>
    <option value="newest"<?php selected( $_POST['select'],'newest', 1 ); ?>>Newest</option>
    <option value="oldest"<?php selected( $_POST['select'], 'oldest', 1 ); ?>>Oldest</option>
    <option value="mcommented"<?php selected( $_POST['select'],'mcommented', 1 ); ?>>Most commented</option>
    <option value="lcommented"<?php selected( $_POST['select'],'lcommented' , 1 ); ?>>least commented</option>
    <option value="prijs"<?php selected( $_POST['select'],'prijs' , 1 ); ?>>prijs</option>
  </select>
</form>
<?php query_posts($query_string . $order); ?>
```

But the last selection option 'prijs' is not working.

Can somebody help me? Or do you need more information?

Sorry for my English if it's not totaly correct.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `query_posts` try using `WP_Query` class. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

This is example from codex:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
'meta_key'   => 'age',
'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
'order'      => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'age',
        'value'   => array( 3, 4 ),
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ),
),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `meta_key` so it knows which meta value to compare the numbers of.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

```
$order = "&order=ASC&meta_key=prijs&orderby=meta_value_num";
```

More info: [Custom query with orderby meta_value of custom field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15477/custom-query-with-orderby-meta-value-of-custom-field#answer-15499)