# How to order by post_status?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I'm using [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) like this:

```
$posts = get_posts(array('orderby' => 'post_status'))
```

which is not possible cause it's not in the allowed keys in the [`parse_orderby()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2217) method

How to get around this limitation?

Comment: look at meta_key and meta_query in orderby.
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15477/custom-query-with-orderby-meta-value-of-custom-field

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`'posts_orderby'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_orderby/) filter to change the SQL performed.

Note that:

- using `get_posts()` you need to set `'suppress_filters'` argument of `false` for the filter to be performed
- if you don't explicitly set `'post_status'` you'll get only published posts (so no much to order)

Code sample:

```
$filter = function() {
  return 'post_status ASC';
};

add_filter('posts_orderby', $filter);

$posts = get_posts('post_status' => 'any', 'suppress_filters' => false);

remove_filter('posts_orderby', $filter);
```

Comment: Best solution so far. This requires PHP 5.3 though!?

Comment: @revaxarts yes. Use a named function instead of a anonymous function for 5.2 compat. But... really?

Comment: yes, really ;) thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'custom_post_status', 10,2);
function custom_post_status($args, $wp_query){
  if($wp_query->query_vars['orderby'] == 'post_status') {
    if($wp_query->query_vars['order']) {
        return 'post_status '.$wp_query->query_vars['order'];
    }
    else {
        return 'post_status ASC';
    }
  }
  return $args;
}
```

Adding this would enable 'orderby'  => 'post_status' in WP_Query