# ORDER BY custom field value

Tags: custom-field, meta-query, order, sort

Based on example here https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/

I'd like to modify the query

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'state_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'state',
        'value' => 'Wisconsin',
    ),
    'city_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'city',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ), 
),
'orderby' => 'city_clause') );
```

to be able to get all posts where `state` is 'Wisconsin' OR  `timezone` is 'central' ORDER BY `population` DESC

Comment: Please do not ask for the same thing in two different threads :)

Comment: Sure - sorry about that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom query with orderby meta\_value of custom field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15477/custom-query-with-orderby-meta-value-of-custom-field)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create groups of meta_queries using specific compare operation on them, and since you want to order based in a single custom field, you can keep the order declaration dedicated to the single meta field. So:

```
$q = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        'meta_key' => 'population', //setting the meta_key which will be used to order
        'orderby' => 'meta_value', //if the meta_key (population) is numeric use meta_value_num instead
        'order' => 'DESC', //setting order direction
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND', //setting relation between queries group
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR', //setting relation between this inside query
                array(
                    'key' => 'state',
                    'value' => 'Wisconsin',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'timezone',
                    'value' => 'central',
                )
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'city',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            )
        )
    )           
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be done like this:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            'state_clause' => array(
                'key' => 'state',
                'value' => array( 'Wisconsin' ), //allowed values
                'compare' => 'IN' // state must be in array above
            ),
            'state_clause' => array(
                'key' => 'timezone',
                'value' => 'central',
                'compare' => '='
            ),
        ),
        'city_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'city_clause' => 'DESC',
    ),
) );
```

Comment: Thanks @fischi - but I have two problems with that solution: 1) the value of 'state_clause' in meta_query array gets overwritten - so only last declaration stays in ('timezone') if u actually dump the query. 2) the 'relation' => 'OR' ruins the logic of a query - now result is all posts as `population` exists in all cases (and we just want the ones where `state` is 'Wisconsin' or `timezone` is 'central'

Comment: see answer for update.

Comment: Thank you! repeating 'state_clause' in the array for  state and timezone keys would not work -  so I needed to do it as @Bruno Cantuaria sugested above. However, Bruno's solution did not work for me without declaring city_clause and calling it in 'orderby'. So thanks again

Comment: No Problem. Glad to help!