# How to put orderby on a custom field in query_posts

Tags: query-posts

I have the following query in my query_posts and want to add order by to this. Order by will be on another custom field and sorted by desc order.

Here is my existing query.

```
//show all active posts for this taxonomy
 query_posts( array(
   'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   APP_CUSTOM_TAX => $term->slug,
   'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
   'orderby' => 'date', //Instead of this, i want to use custom field like 'votes','date'
   'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
             array(
                'key' => 'offer_type',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
              ),
              array(
                'key' => 'offer_type',
                'value' => 'top',
                'compare' => '!=',
              )
      ))
);
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15499/68328

Comment: If you search this site for "orderby meta" you'll see that there are many answers to this.

Comment: @RameshPardhi  - Yes, but my challenge is i want the custom field in where clause as well as orderby and i am not sure how to put it in both.

Comment: Thanks @RameshPardhi, i was finally able to do the orderby with this link on one of the columns, but now i have to do orderby on mutlple columns and it is not working. Any suggestions. 

`'orderby' => 'votes',
 'meta_key' => 'votes',`

I tried this but doesn't work as expected

`'orderby' => array('votes','date'),
 'meta_key' => 'votes',`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) - you use `'orderby' => 'meta_value'`. Specifically, scroll down a bit and read **'orderby' with multiple 'meta_key's**

Comment: i looked at that - but my challenge is i want the custom field in where clause as well as orderby and i am not sure how to put it in both