# How to update serialized post meta?

Tags: posts, array

I have serialized post meta. And i want to update single meta key. It looks like this:

[image]

In array:

```
$kisiArray = array(
   'option1' => 'foo',
   'option2' => 'bar',
   'option3' => 'apple',
   'option4' => 'orange'
);
```

I want to update only `'option3'` to `'peach'` so i am using [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) function.

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'themeOps', ??? );
```

But i don't know what i must put the `meta_value` section. When i pust **peach**, it changes all meta keys to **peach**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must read custom field `themeOps` first, update index `option3` in array and then save/update whole array.

```
$kisiArray = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'themeOps' );
$kisiArray['option3'] = 'peach';
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'themeOps', $kisiArray );
```

---

**Update** (sort by custom field)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'meta_key'   => 'themeOps_option3',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

More examples you find in [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: Thank you it works. Last question, do you know how to use $kisiArray['option3'] in orderby meta_value_num? (I will set integer)

Comment: @bilimokur You can't use custom field with serialized array as value to sort posts.  Move `$kisiArray['option3']` to separate custom field (e.g. `themeOps_option3`). When you will have the 'option3' value in a separate meta key, 
then you can use this key to sort posts as described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/246206/147428)