# Order Posts in Custom Order

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

I am trying to create a custom way to order my new custom post type.

Here is what I am envisioning:

- There would be a custom way to order posts in an entirely unique order for display (Number, automatic value, etc.) This would be so I could avoid needing to manually change a ton of publication dates on posts to get the right order.
- If there was no number/automatic value/etc. entered then it would display based on when it was published at the end of the list.

I am using CMB2 for the meta-data fields on my custom post type.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas? I realize that this is a complicated problem, but I want to be able to order posts in a custom order that is not by author, date published, or title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `register_post_type()`, you can specify the `'page-attributes' => true` property, and you'll get the "menu order" metabox which you see on pages. With this you can custom order your items, where the default is always 0, which means they will always show, even if you don't set a value.

You don't actually have to set the `page-attributes` attribute to use the the `menu_order` post property/column. You can set that value programmatically. To query with the custom ordering in place, you can use the `menu_order` property in your `WP_Query` args: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Comment: In Wordpress 6.2.2, I needed to add this  to the `supports` options, e.g. `'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'page-attributes'),`. Simple setting a `page-attributes` option seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score -1):

You could just add a 'priority' or 'order' custom field (number) to your post type and order based on that.

See [Custom query with orderby meta_value of custom field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15479/967), [wp_query / #order-orderby-parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters)

Comment: Yes. I had thought of this, but the problem I run into is if there is no number/priority in the meta-data box, then it will not be displayed. This could be a problem for clients that use this feature that don't know what they should be looking for.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CMB2, can't you just set a default value (either 0, or a maximum, say 999)? 
Also, I would've thought even without a value, you use the _meta_key_ just for _orderby_ so posts without ranking should still be displayed - just at the end?