# Filter posts in pre_get_posts order by meta value date (desc or asc)

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying to order the post by a meta value but it is not working the right way.

I store the date in the post meta value like this `01 December 2019 10:00`. Now I want to sort the posts `desc` or `asc` like the `date`.

I tried the following code:

```
$orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' );
            $sorting = $query->get( 'order' );

            if ('month' == $orderby ) {



                $query->set( 'meta_key', 'preferred_date' );
                $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value');
                $query->set( 'order', $sorting );

            }
```

I use the code in the action `pre_get_posts`.

Did anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: just set `orderby` to string of `'meta_value'` as in this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15499/76440
then you can set `order` to `ASC` or `DESC`

Comment: This is not working

Comment: try posting the full code that you have now, otherwise no one will know your next step

Comment: My full code now is: $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' );
            $sorting = $query->get( 'order' );

            if ('month' == $orderby ) {



                $query->set( 'meta_key', 'preferred_date' );
                $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value');
                $query->set( 'order', $sorting );

            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I have not stored the date values in the right way. I had to save it like `Y-m-d` or `Y-m-d H:i`